# Create UI for Application

Tags: android

I want to create Application which looks i this way:
[image]

I will have lets say 6 Scroollable Lists (A,B,C,D,E,F). They should change by touch event.
For example we see Scrollable List B, I touch screen and move to left and next I see Scrollable List C, I touch screen and move it to right and I see Scrollable List B).

The name do Scrollable List (NameOfScrollableList shoud be change with touch event for Scrollable List)

How to do it? (I am not asking for code. I want to know a proper aproach to this problem :) )

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are looking for `ViewPager`
[This might help you](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

Comment: I looks fine, but what about sync of scrolling between ScrollableList (it will by page of ViewPager) and chnage of NameOfScrollableList ?
I want to synchronized change page with change name of this page in separate component (lets say horizontal list view)

Comment: You will change the name of page inside OnPageChangeListener, which you add to the viewPager

Comment: ok, but is it possible to animate change of page name like change page. It means for example I shift page and List of name is also shifted?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to horizontally scroll between your lists. Have a look at [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), which is ideal for [horizontal scrolling](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). The put a ListView inside each page of ViewPager.

That's what I'd do.